# Can't add ScrollBar to ScrollablePositionedList (it doesn't have a ScrollController)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-scrollbar

I'm using the [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) package, and have it rendering a large dynamic list. It works very well. However, I need my list to have a scrollbar (something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbkIQSvwnZc)). So far, this is impossible.

Does anyone know how to do it?

My code looks as follows:

```
Scrollbar(
          child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(
              parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ),
            itemCount: posts.length + 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index == 0) {
                return Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('post content'),
                  ),
                );
              } else if (posts[index - 1].isRoot) {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  child: Text('ROOT COMMENT, index: ${index - 1}'),
                );
              } else {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  child: Text('Threaded comment, index: ${index - 1}'),
                );
              }
            },
            itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
            itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
          ),
        ),
```

I realize a `ScrollBar` needs to have the same `ScrollController` as the scroll view it's wrapping, however, I'm not sure how to get this because `ScrollablePositionedList` doesn't have a `ScrollController`.

Errors in my terminal after running the project with the solution provided (little snippet of it):

```
Performing hot restart...                           
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter.widgets-6
d6dac5f19b577338d912d3c9a45d26593e0a475/packages/scr
ollable_positioned_list/lib/src/scrollable_positione
d_list.dart:437:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which
excludes null.
Performing hot restart...                           
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from
 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
 ('../../tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/sche
 duler/binding.dart').
Performing hot restart...                           
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallbac
      k((_) {
Performing hot restart...                           
                       ^
Performing hot restart...                           
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter.widgets-6
d6dac5f19b577338d912d3c9a45d26593e0a475/packages/scr
ollable_positioned_list/lib/src/scrollable_positione
d_list.dart:484:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which
excludes null.
Performing hot restart...                           
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from
 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
 ('../../tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/sche
 duler/binding.dart').
Performing hot restart...                           
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallb
        ack((_) {
Performing hot restart...                           
                         ^
Performing hot restart...                           
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter.widgets-6
d6dac5f19b577338d912d3c9a45d26593e0a475/packages/scr
ollable_positioned_list/lib/src/positioned_list.dart
:298:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation
'!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
Performing hot restart...                           
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from
 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
 ('../../tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/sche
 duler/binding.dart').
Performing hot restart...                           
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallbac
      k((_) {
Performing hot restart...                           
                       ^
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 195ms.
```

After fixing the warnings (reply to comment), this now occurs randomly when using it:

```
The following assertion was thrown while notifying status listeners for AnimationController:
The Scrollbar's ScrollController has no ScrollPosition attached.
A Scrollbar cannot be painted without a ScrollPosition.
The Scrollbar attempted to use the provided ScrollController. This ScrollController should be
associated with the ScrollView that the Scrollbar is being applied to. When providing your
own
ScrollController, ensure both the Scrollbar and the Scrollable widget use the same one.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      RawScrollbarState._debugCheckHasValidScrollPosition.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart:1475:9)
#1      RawScrollbarState._debugCheckHasValidScrollPosition
(package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart:1500:6)
#2      RawScrollbarState._validateInteractions
(package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart:1445:14)
#3      AnimationLocalStatusListenersMixin.notifyStatusListeners
(package:flutter/src/animation/listener_helpers.dart:233:19)
#4      AnimationController._checkStatusChanged
(package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:815:7)
#5      AnimationController._startSimulation
(package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:749:5)
#6      AnimationController._animateToInternal
(package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:612:12)
#7      AnimationController.reverse
(package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:494:12)
#8      RawScrollbarState._maybeStartFadeoutTimer.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart:1630:37)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and
dart:async-patch)

The AnimationController notifying status listeners was:
  AnimationController#72402(◀ 1.000)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a `ScrollConfiguration`:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: _ScrollbarBehavior(),
          child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('$index')),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class _ScrollbarBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildScrollbar(BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return Scrollbar(child: child, controller: details.controller);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You may see my old answer here for detail steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73279565/12838877

you can modify, but still have some `bug` when apply the `ScrollController`

try some alternative from [issue#305](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/pull/305), its not good enough but you can apply it.

```
final ItemScrollController itemSctr = ItemScrollController();
...

body: Scrollbar(
  controller: itemSctr.scrollController, 
  child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
```

Comment: It works, except in my terminal when running the project, I get a bunch of errors, any idea if they're bad, and how to remove them? I posted a clip of the errors in the question! I feel so close to getting it solved!

Comment: which flutter version do you use?  if its  v3.0.0  or above , i think you can ignore it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103561

Comment: I use the newest Flutter version (3.x). Should I clone the repo on GitHub with the fixed code, and then remove ? and ! operators? This could solve the problem but it seems like a very tedious process. I dislike having warning messages in the console that can’t be removed

Comment: Forked the google repo myself, changed the same code post-null safety , and my version now works without any of the warnings. However, both your version and mine have a bunch of errors messages that are randomly spit out (literally seemingly randomly), after a while of using the scroll. Output of error added to  question.

Answer (score 0):

anyone who requires it can use this repo to access scrollController. This should only be done in pubspec.yaml

```
 scrollable_positioned_list:
git:
  url: https://github.com/nabil6391/flutter.widgets.git
  ref: master
  path: packages/scrollable_positioned_list/
```

And the result

```
    Scrollbar(
    thickness: 8,
    radius: Radius.circular(4),
    controller: itemScrollController.scrollController,
    child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
          itemCount: totalItems,
          itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                color: getItemColor(index, context),
                child: buildDropdownList(context, index),
            );
          },
      ),
 )
```

Comment: I searched for this for days and found this to be the best solution

Comment: Still bugs out.